# Prove: $\frac{r_a}{bc} + \frac{r_b}{ca} + \frac{r_c}{ab} = \frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{2R}$, for circumradius R, inradius $r$, and exradii $r_x$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

> In $\triangle ABC$, prove: 
>   $$\frac{r_a}{bc} + \frac{r_b}{ca} + \frac{r_c}{ab} = \frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{2R}$$ 
>   for circumradius $R$, inradius $r$, and exradii $r_a$, $r_b$, $r_c$ in the standard arrangement.

It is known that $r_a = \sqrt{\dfrac{s\left(s-b\right)\left(s-c\right)}{s-a}}$, where $s = \dfrac12\left(a+b+c\right)$ is the semiperimeter of $\triangle ABC$. Similar formulas exist for $r_b$, $r_c$ and $r$. But how does $R$ connect with all of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will use the $\sum_{cyc}$ notation for cyclic sums:
$$
\sum_{cyc}f(a,b,c) = f(a,b,c)+f(b,c,a)+f(c,a,b)
$$
for any function $f$. Also, let $\Delta$ be the area of triangle $ABC$.

We have:
$$ \frac{r_a}{bc}=\frac{\Delta}{(s-a)bc}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\sin(A)}{s-a}=\frac{a}{4R(s-a)}\tag{1}$$
hence we have to prove that:
$$ 2+\sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{s-a} = \frac{4R}{r} \tag{2}$$
that is equivalent to:
$$ 2r+\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{\cot\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)} = 2R\tag{3}$$
or to:
$$ 2r+\sum_{cyc}2R(1-\cos(A)) = 2R\tag{4}$$
that follows from [Carnot's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

Using [Sine Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines)

and
$r_a=4R\sin\dfrac A2\cos\dfrac B2\cos\dfrac C2,$
$r=4R\sin\dfrac A2\sin\dfrac B2\sin\dfrac C2,$

$11(v)$,$12(iii)$ respectively of [Properties of triangle](http://aieee.examcrazy.com/maths/formula-tips/Properties-and-Solution-of-Triangle.asp) ,

$\dfrac{r_a}{bc}=\cdots=\dfrac{\sin^2\dfrac A2}r$

Now $\cos A=1-2\sin^2\dfrac A2\iff2\sin^2\dfrac A2=1-\cos A$

Finally use $\cos A+\cos B+\cos C=1+\dfrac rR,11(vi)$ of [Properties of triangle](http://aieee.examcrazy.com/maths/formula-tips/Properties-and-Solution-of-Triangle.asp)

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Using $\Delta = rs =r_a(s-a) = r_b(s-b) = r_c(s-c) = \frac{abc}{4R},$ the equality we need to prove turns into
$$\frac{\Delta}{bc(s-a)}+\frac{\Delta}{ca(s-b)}+\frac{\Delta}{ab(s-c)}=\frac{s}{\Delta}-\frac{2\Delta}{abc}$$
\begin{align*}
\text{i.e.} \;\;\; \frac{a}{s-a}+\frac{b}{s-b}+\frac{c}{s-c}& = \frac{sabc}{\Delta^2}-2 \\
&= \frac{abc}{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}-2
\end{align*}
Which is clearly true.

$QED.$